# python, loops: searching against a list to see if item is present, appending to new list

Tags: python, loops

I am trying to make a program where my students will enter their ID numbers so I can (later in the code) automate sending attendance, and record who has handed in homework and who hasn't so emails can be sent to parents. I have everything else made, but I cannot get the inputting of student ID's working.

What I am trying to do:
1)make sure that their input is 7 characters long
2)check their ID exists in 'fakeID' 
2a)have the students confirm their name from 'classNames' with a y/n. 
2b) append their name into `inputIDList` 
3) if the input is == to 9999990 exit the loop.

What it is doing:
1) asking for input 
2) moving on in the code and not looping
3) not appending `inputIDList`

I think I am making this too complicated for my current skill level.

edit:
The loop is not checking to see if the inputed ID is in my `fakeID` list. 
Also, it isnt looping for, so once the input is entered it continues on with the next set of code.

edit2:
updated code that works. :D

```
fakeID = ['1111111','1111112','1111113','1111114','1111115']
classNames = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4', 'name5']
toplist = list(zip(fakeID, classNames))


inputIDList =[]
def inputID():
 while True:
     id = input('Please enter your student ID and hit Enter')

     if id == '9999990':
         print('Done')
         break

     if id in fakeID:
         inputIDList.append(id)
         print('recorder')
         continue

     if id not in fakeID:
         print('I do not know this ID. Please try again.')
         continue
```

Comment: You do `inputIDList = [''] `, and then `for i in inputIDList:`. This is just going to run once, with `i` set to `''`. And you never use `i` inside that loop. So, the whole loop is pointless; you could replace it with the same code without a loop and it will do the same thing.

Comment: Just checking the length of the ```s``` variable, to see if it is 7 characters long, will not guarantee you get a valid ID. What happens if the student input something like ```abcdefg``` as his ID?

Comment: More generally, which part of this are you stuck on? Your code is over-complicated in multiple places, as you say, and I don't really know which area you've hit a brick wall in. If you can [edit] your question to be clearer about that, it would be a lot easier to answer.

Comment: But meanwhile, some general advice: Can you pull that piece out into a separate function? If so, can you throw away the current implementation of that separate function and rewrite it from scratch, using what you learned from your first attempt? (That doesn't mean you're a failed noob or something; building prototypes to learn where the hard parts are and then throwing away the code and writing the right thing is how experienced programmers deal with problems they aren't sure how to solve at first.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something to get you started:

```
fakeID = {'1111111','1111112','1111113','1111114','1111115'}

while True:
    id = input('Please enter your student ID and hit Enter')

    if id == '9999990':
        print('Done')
        break

    if id not in fakeID:
        print('I do not know this ID. Please try again.')
        continue
```

Comment: Thank you, this gives me an idea on how to do this :D

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your problem correctly then I suppose that you are trying to save the ID numbers of the students in **inputIdList** and then check whether a particular ID is in **inputIdList** or not. In the last *if* condition you are trying to compare a List type object with a String type object which will definitely throw an TypeError. Instead define the following function and call it in the if condition.

```
def check_list(id):
    try:
        inputIdList.index(id)
        return True
    except TypeError:
        return False
```

[list.index()](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) method tries to find the element in the list and returns the  index number of the element. And then call this function in your *if* condition.

```
if check_list('9999990'):
    print('done') 
    #break
```

Furthermore there is no need to assign `inputIdList = [""]` if you have already intialized it to `inputIdList = []`.
If the problem persists please send the output in the thread.

Answer (score 0):

as Abarnert said you need to restructure your method. but I think I found where you were stuck.
after you have checked for the length of input number, you should check whether that number matches any `fakeID`,and get the corresponding class name.
so your first loop should be like this

```
for i in toplist:
```

rather than

```
for i in [i for i,x in enumerate(inputIDList) if x == fakeID]:
```

since `inputIDList` is empty your program will not go inside the loop. And inside the changed loop you should be checking

```
if s == fakeID
```

This is the limit of what I could understand of your desired operation. But if you need further help just ask.
cheers.